# Difference between Amazon Security group and firewall

Tags: security, amazon-ec2

Is there any difference between the Amazon EC2 "Security groups" and a regular firewall?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's no major difference. EC2 security groups are basically firewall configurations that are easier to keep track of and automatically apply and clear as machines are added and removed from your groups.